# Settings bundle with non-standard name

Tags: iphone, ipad, build-process

May I use a settings bundle in xcode which is not called Settings.bundle?

If I have multiple settings bundles (for multiple build targets), must I define these additional names anywhere? My application seems to always look for one called Settings.bundle.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you who aren't good at shell scripts, here's a template version of what I used.  In addition to a Debug and Release build, we also had a Debug-Special build with its own Info.plist in the build settings, and a different Settings.bundle/Root.plist file.  I created copies of the Setting.bundle/ folder to Settings(original).bundle and Settings(special).bundle and added this script to the pre-build:

subdir="original" ; [[ $CONFIGURATION = "Debug-Special" ]] && subdir="special" ; cp "$SRCROOT/Settings($subdir).bundle/Root.plist" "$SRCROOT/Settings.bundle/"

Be sure to select your project to add the environment variables to the shell that runs the script.

I realize the thread is pretty old in code years but it is still relevant, and hopefully this will save the next person who finds it some time.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding a script in pre-build where the alternative bundle is renamed to Settings.bundle